# Printing certain JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm retrieving JSON data through NAPALM, it outputs quite alot of data and I want to be able to print only a few elements from it. My current code is;

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
import json
import paramiko

driver = get_network_driver('nxos_ssh')
LD9AGGSW01 = driver('10.249.9.44', 'username', 'password',)
LD9AGGSW01.open()

json_data = LD9AGGSW01.get_facts()

print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

and the JSON data i get back is;

```
{
    "uptime": 58404121,
    "vendor": "Cisco",
    "os_version": "7.0(3)I3(1)",
    "serial_number": "FDO211410B8",
    "model": "Nexus9000 C92160YC-X chassis",
    "hostname": "Nexus-Switch-01",
    "fqdn": "",
    "interface_list": [
        "mgmt0",
        "Ethernet1/1",
        "Ethernet1/2",
    ]
}
```

How would I pass through things such as the "model","hostname data" and "mgmt0" only to a print function?

Comment: What does `print(json_data)` look like?

Comment: And what is `type(json_data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print a partial dictionary, you can try:

```py
print(
    {
        "model": json_data["model"],
        "hostname": json_data["hostname"],
        "first_interface": json_data["interface_list"][0],
    }
)
```

You can also implement an extraction function, like this:

```py
def extract(data):
    return {
        "model": data["model"],
        "hostname": data["hostname"],
        "first_interface": data["interface_list"][0],
    }


print(extract(json_data))
```